Trying to extend the lower section to the right and how to measure the inside to 2"

Trying to extend the lower section to the right and how to measure the inside to 2"

Hi. When you say "the inside", do you mean the distance between faces, or in the circled area the distance between where the fillets run out? If it's between faces and if you can find 2 vertices that line up in both the X and Z axes, or in the case of between fillets the X-axis, you could use the Blender addon MeasureIt Tools to show the dimension as you move the part in order to get the 2" dimension. It also depends on what your dimensional tolerance is. You might not have to have the vertices exactly aligned. Continued...

If you're not familiar with the addon, this is the last, not overly detailed manual page for it : https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.1//addons/3d_view/measureit.html If you look on YouTube, there are several videos about it.
